# Casting string 'Infinity' to Infinity from dotenv file

Tags: node.js

I have a NodeJS app, and I am working on getting some config into a dotenv file. In my app I use a var `MAX_PAGES` which I set in local testing to 5 or something, but on production this var is set to `Infinity`.

When I use `Infinity` in my dotenv then I get the string `'Infinity'`.

I know I have other options such as:

- using 999999999999999
- Setting the dotenv var to -1 and if it is -1 in NodeJS I use Infinity
- etc

Just wondering if a simple cast would be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest answer is `eval()`, but also the least safe:

```
eval('Infinity') // Infinity
```

But in your case `Number()` works just as well:

```
Number('Infinity') // Infinity
```

Alternatively, include a check:

```
if(MAX_PAGES === 'Infinity') MAX_PAGES = Infinity;
```

Comment: Ah right the infamous `eval`. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I replaced it with `Number()`. Much safer ;)

Comment: Ah great, that seems to do the job quite perfect!